# Multi-layer insulation for private houses?

Tags: insulation

Space vehicles and military systems use an advanced technology called [multi-layer insulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-layer_insulation)(MLI) to manage thermal conditions. It is very expensive.

Are there MLI systems that are available for use in private homes?

Comment: From the page you linked: "In its basic form, it does not appreciably insulate against other thermal losses such as heat conduction or convection." Those seem like deal-breakers to me.

Comment: No, because you are not in space.

Answer (score 4):

No. The product in question has been designed for applications where low weight and resistance to radiant heat transfer are the dominant goals, and justify a high price. Residential construction involves different goals (resistance primarily to conduction and convection; low cost; ease of installation and retrofitting), so the product's high price is unjustifiable.

The closest residential equivalent would be sheets of foil-faced polyiso--installed correctly of course, with the foil facing an airspace of 1" or greater.